# Bike upgrade wheels shifters cassette

Tags: wheels, upgrades, transmission

Hi everyone I have a boardman comp hybrid nine speed how easy is it to change it to a eleven speed for the extra four gears.

[image]
<sub>From https://www.bikeradar.com/reviews/bikes/road-bikes/boardman-comp-review-2/</sub>

Answer (score 2):

If you need a different range of gears (eg, an easier low gear), you don't need to add more gears, you can just get a different cassette and probably a new chain.

If you really want more gears, you'll at minimum need a new cassette, chain, rear shifter, and shifter cable. Your existing rear derailleur might be compatible, although I'm having trouble digging up the specs on this bike.

Either way, you'll probably want a shop to do the work. Check with your local bike shop to get an estimate.

Comment: Given the bike's age, it may also need a new freehub body - with OEM wheels, we can assume that in practice this means a new rear wheel.

Answer (score 1):

According to the specs - this bike is from 2007 and as sold had a 10 speed Tiagra chain and "a 105 rear derailleur designed for 10 speed systems"

So, going to 10 from 9 needs a new cassette, and a new right-hand shifter with 10 positions.  That's all, though a new chain will be wise.

To go to more, you start needing a lot more parts and it gets expensive fast.  Its a 16-year old aluminium frame bike, so you might choose to just keep it running.

Personally, I have both a 7 speed and 10 speed road bikes, and I've never thought "I wish I had smaller gaps between these cogs" whereas I have definitely wished for a lower-low gear.  When you say "four more gears" that will depend more on what tooth-counts you select on the new cassette.